# Chrome's "share to device" and "click to call" keep sending to the wrong phone

Tags: chrome-for-android

I have 2 Android devices of the same brand and model, one is for gaming and such and has no SIM card, the other one is my main phone with the SIM card and able to make a phone call.

I discovered this very useful "share to device" and "click to call" function as it sends to the correct phone each time. However, since yesterday, whenever I try to do it, it keeps sending it to the other wrong phone. And I seem to have no control whatsoever on which phone to select for the desktop Chrome to send to.

When I click "send to your device", only that one option shows up and it keeps sending to the wrong phone.

I did not change any settings on my Android phones. All sync and notification have been enabled.

Is there a way to show and choose the target device?

Comment: From your desktop's Chrome, browse to `chrome://sync-internals/` - Sync Node Browser - Device Info. Do you see your Android devices from there?

Comment: Yes, I actually see both phones in there, and since are the same phone they have identical names. I also tried to share a page from my phone (Phone I want to work) to the chrome browsers and it works!!! But I still cannot get any sharing from my desktop chrome to the phone I want.

Comment: I found out the problem, I installed an app called Tasker, and it blocked all notification send from my chrome desktop. I uninstall it and it works again.

Comment: That's strange because I also use Tasker, did you know why it's blocking the notification? Anyway, looks like you've found the solution by yourself, which is great! Consider post it as a proper answer since [self-answering is not only allowed, but even encouraged!](//android.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). Thanks!